# How do I open files from Quickfix List in Vim when using EasyGrep?

Tags: list, vim, grep

I'm relatively new to Vim. I've just installed [EasyGrep](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2438) but can't figure out how to open the files listed in the Quickfix List when I do a search. I can cycle through files containing a matching word using `:cn` or open a file by double-clicking with my mouse but when I press `<Enter>` nothing happens. I've also tried `go` and `t` but neither of these are working.

Can anyone help?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read [`:h quickfix`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html) and [`:h quickref`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickref.txt.html). Good luck! :-)

Comment: Thanks @ryuichiro ! I have found lots out here that's really useful however. Apparently pressing <Enter> should open the file under the cursor but it doesn't :/    

'In the quickfix window, each line is one error.  The line number is equal to
the error number.  You can use ":.cc" to jump to the error under the cursor.
Hitting the <Enter> key or double-clicking the mouse on a line has the same
effect.'

Comment: Hm, it is possible that you enter is mapped to something. You can check it by `:verbose map <CR>`.

Comment: That was it! Thanks, I had it mapped to make a new line: nmap <CR> o<Esc>

Comment: If you have a mapping for <CR> that you want to keep, except for when you are in quickfix, you can use `autocmd BufReadPost quickfix nnoremap <buffer> <CR> <CR>` in your `~/.vimrc` to undefine the mapping for quickfix as pointed out [here](https://superuser.com/questions/815416/hitting-enter-in-the-quickfix-window-doesnt-work/815422#815422?newreg=fb0f00f67ca940dfbfea198f7f9d6885)

Comment: I've added an answer to make the information within the above comments available more conveniently and to mark this question as being answered ;)

Answer (score 7):

As already mentioned by @ryuichiro, and then quoted by @Alistair Colling, the quickfix documentation ([:h quickfix](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html) and [:hquickref](https://vimhelp.org/quickref.txt.html)) provides an answer for how to open files within a quickfix list:

> You can use `:.cc` to jump to the error under the cursor.
>   Hitting the `<Enter>` key or double-clicking the mouse on a line has the same
>   effect.  The file containing the error is opened in the window above the
>   quickfix window.

Make sure that your `<Enter>` Key (`<CR>`) is not mapped so that it properly works. As already mentioned by @ryuichiro, this can be checked with

```
:verbose map <CR>
```

If you have a global mapping for `<CR>` (e.g. in my case a mapping from the NERDtree plugin), you can undefine it just for when you are within a quickfix list based on adding the following line to your `~/.vimrc` as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/815416/hitting-enter-in-the-quickfix-window-doesnt-work/815422#815422?newreg=fb0f00f67ca940dfbfea198f7f9d6885):

```
autocmd BufReadPost quickfix nnoremap <buffer> <CR> <CR>
```